# How to join multiple numbers together as a string in PHP?

Tags: php, html, string

I need to create a comma separated string of numbers.

The issue I'm running into is that, in the end, I'm getting a total of all the numbers when it should be like:

`2, 10, 35, 56, 67', etc.`

Here's what I'm doing:

```
$field_ids = '';

// begin while loop
<?php $field_ids = bp_get_the_profile_field_ids(); ?>
// end while loop

// begin while loop
<?php $field_ids += bp_get_the_profile_field_ids(); ?>
// end while loop

<input type="hidden" name="field_ids" id="field_ids" value="<?php echo $field_ids; ?>">
```

How can I get this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="field_ids" id="field_ids" value="2, 10, 35, 56, 67">
```

instead of this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="field_ids" id="field_ids" value="170">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you could gather them as an array, then use `implode()` to do this:

```
$field_ids = array(); // initialize as array

while(...) { // begin while loop block
    $field_ids[] = bp_get_the_profile_field_ids(); // push it inside
} // end while loop block

$field_ids = implode(', ', $field_ids); // implode/glue those ids by comma

<input type="hidden" name="field_ids" id="field_ids" value="<?php echo $field_ids; ?>">
```

By using `+=` you're continually adding them up until the end of the loop resulting to its summation.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use this operator `+=` use this: `.=`

So instead of this:

```
<?php $field_ids += bp_get_the_profile_field_ids(); ?>
```

write this:

```
<?php $field_ids .= bp_get_the_profile_field_ids(); . ", " ?>
```